# Difference between summation for "$\aleph$" terms and summation for "$\aleph_0$" terms

Tags: integration, power-series, fractional-calculus

Addition: **Could we say that the dimension of a space is "$\aleph_0$" or"$\aleph$"?** I guess that **every elementary functions can be uniquely expanded as integer order power series expansion under given $\aleph_0$ many of linear independent mononomials**, and correspndngly,  **every non-elementary functions can be uniquely expanded as real-order power series expansion under given $\aleph$ many of linear independent mononomials**.
Maybe this guess has already been given... Do someone else know more about this domain?

---

Before narrating my problem, please let me recall the consensus of Riemannian integral condensely: The interval $[a,b]$, on which a function $f(x)$ is defined, can be separated into many smaller intervals like
$$a=x_0<x_1<\dotsb<x_n=b.$$
Then the Riemannian sum
$$\sigma=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_k)\Delta x_k,\qquad \xi_k\in[x_k,x_{k+1})$$
becomes the integral of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ when $\max(x_{k+1}-x_k)=\max\Delta x_k\rightarrow0$.

Clearly, we can only separates the interval into integer many smaller interval. If we take a set $A$ whose elements are each smaller interval divided from $[a,b]$, then the cardinal number of this set (and then the number of smaller sections) is at most $\aleph_0$, equal to the cardinal number of $\mathbb Z$.

However, for an integral $\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx$, $f(x)$ is defined for every $x\in[a,b]$, since $[a,b]$ is a continuum with cardinal number $\aleph>\aleph_0$, there are also $\aleph$ of $f(x)\mathrm dx$'s to be summed.

**Here seems to be a difference between summation for $\aleph$ terms and summation for $\aleph_0$ terms… but what is it in essence? And what is the relation between an integral $\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx$ and an infinite term sum $\sum_{x=a}^bf(x)(\text{for all $x\in[a,b]$})$?**

I know gramatically "cardinal number" and "ordinal number" are for different use in English…but I couldn't find a better way to express "number".

---

Background of this problem: I'm still trying to generalize a fractal derivative.
I hope to generalize harmonic polynomials to fractal power, i.e. if there exists a $k$-homogeneous polynomial
$$p(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)=\sum_{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dotsc,\alpha_n}{x_1}^{\alpha_1}{x_2}^{\alpha_2}\dotsm{x_n}^{\alpha_n},\qquad \sum_i\alpha_i=k\in\text{$\mathbb R$ or even $\mathbb C$}$$
such that
$$\Delta p=0.$$

Then I began to thinking about its simplest appearance: could a function be expanded in the form as
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i, \qquad i\in[0,+\infty)? $$
I have tacitly let that $x^i$ is already defined for all $i\in\mathbb R$, and hence the term of this summation, or the "cardinal number" might be $\aleph$ (is it?).
Commom method to expand a function, however, just uses integers, like
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i,\qquad i\in\mathbb Z$$
and its term is "$\aleph_0$".

For an example, we already have Fourier expansion for $$\exp x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \cfrac{x^k}{k!}, \quad k=0,1,2,...\in \mathbb N$$

Then how about an expansion in the form of the summation of '$\aleph$' many of term as
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb R_{\geq 0}}\cfrac{x^k}{k!}(?)$$

I guess this may relates to $\Gamma(x)$ or others.

I found that it's difficult to put a fractal expansion $\sum a_ix^i$ ino an integral $\int a_ix^i$, and then began to consider what is the difference between those two kinds of summation?

Comment: You seem to be using $\aleph$ for the least infinite cardinal and $\aleph_0$ for the cardinal of the continuum; this is something like the opposite of the usual notation.  I believe your question might be answered by the fact that, if an unordered sum $\sum_k \Delta x_k = b - a$ of non-negative terms converges, then only countably many of the $\Delta x_k$ can be non-$0$.  Or perhaps it would be answered by Fourier integrals of non-periodic functions, as opposed to Fourier series of periodic functions?

Comment: @LSpice: I've occasionally seen $\aleph$ used for the cardinality of the continuum, but this always strikes me as a bad notation choice, because the notation is not very robust with respect to obvious typos -- accidently drop the $0$ and it means something else, plus if the print is small then the presence or absence of $0$ could be overlooked.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, [yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421519/difference-between-summation-for-aleph-terms-and-summation-for-aleph-0#comment1083036_421519), the notation has been fixed since when I [commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421519/difference-between-summation-for-aleph-terms-and-summation-for-aleph-0#comment1082991_421519); I agree that $\aleph$ for the cardinality continuum is OK but not ideal, but I think that one must not use $\aleph_0$ for that cardinality, as the question originally did.

Comment: @LSpice: I knew it had been fixed, and I was simply commenting on the use of $\aleph$ for cardinality of the continuum. As for the OP's notation originally being switched, I considered that to be a bit too egregious to qualify as an example of what I was talking about. Maybe should have said so, since I didn't intend the original OP version to be illustrative of what I was talking about.

Comment: Yes,,, I did arranged my notation according to @LSpice... I'm sorry for this confusing

Comment: The size of the continuum can be written as $\beth(=\beth_1)$, if you really want to disambiguate (and also avoid people thinking of a generic aleph)

Comment: In Kreysig's intro to functional analysis book I happened to see that if one has a Hilbert space (of arbitrary dimension), with a complete orthonormal set, then every element x of the Hilbert space is written as a "Fourier series" with coefficients given by inner products of x and the compl. orth. set., ... and only countably-many of these coefficients are non-zero, so the infinite sum is countable.